# Select values in dataframe within a range

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have two dataframe:

df1:

| ID | Goal |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 10 |
| 3 | 1 |

df2:

| Lower | Upper |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 10 |
| 1 | 7 |
| 3 | 5 |

I am trying to create a new column in `df1` where:

If the values of the `Goal` falls within the `Lower` and `Upper` bound of `df2`, we select the `Goal` value.
If the value is lower than the `Lower` bound we select the `Lower` bound.
If value is higher than the `Upper` bound, we select the `Upper` bound.

Expected output:

| ID | Goal | New Goal |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 5 |
| 2 | 10 | 7 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the indices match, you can use [`pd.Series.clip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.clip.html):

```
df1['New Goal'] = df1['Goal'].clip(df2['Lower'], df2['Upper'])
```

This assumes that the index of `df2` matches that of `df1`.

Comment: This gives NaN.. any reason why?

Comment: @tjjudge Probably because your indices don't match. What's the index on `df2`? As part of your [mcve] provide code to initialize your dfs, not just the output